# Meaning of {} expressions

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming. I am reading a c# book and am having trouble interpreting code. Specifically, how does the {0} and the my_double work below?

```
my_double = 3.14;
my_decimal = 3.14;
Console.WriteLine("\nMy Double: {0}", my_double);
```

I have seen this format several times in the book but it hasn't been explained. I know it is writing this to the console window, but my questions are:

1. What does this mean?
2. Why does it have {0} in curly brackets could this be replaced by any other number say {100}
3. How could multiple variables be used in the last line of code to say print out my_decimal also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) It means the {0} will be replaced with the first (zero-index) parameter after the string. It's similar to the syntax used by `string.Format(...)`.

2) Replacing it with {100} would mean that the 101st parameter would be placed there. That is not a practical use case.

3) You can use multiple variables by adding additional numbers in curly brackets (sequentially) and additional parameters. Like this:

```
int param1 = 1;
string param2 = "hello";
double param3 = 2.5;
Console.WriteLine("This is parameter 1: {0}. This is parameter 2: {1}. This is parameter 3: {2}", param1, param2, param3);
```

Docs:

- Console.WriteLine:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx
- String.Format:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This acts like an indexer for the last arguments of the method. So, it is saying to grab the 0th element, which is `my_double`. It is there so that you can create a simple string without having to write `"blah" + variable + "blah" + variable2...`

If you want to print more items, then just add more to the end and reference them by their index in that final list. IE:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", var0, var1, var2);
```

Comment: ok thanks this is the exact syntax i am familiar with. i come from a java background :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an overload of `Console.WriteLine` that take format specifiers and arguments. What this means is you specify a token to be replaced with the `{x}` syntax. That is a 0 indexed list, so if you added a second property you would have `WriteLine("{0},{1}", value1, value2)`. Docs on that version of `WriteLine` can be found here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works similar to [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can achieve what you are looking for like this:

```
 my_double = 3.14;
 my_decimal = 3.14;

Console.WriteLine(“\nMy Double: {0}\nMy Decimal: {1}”, my_double, my_decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as `String.Format` method:
any occurrence of `{sequentialInteger}` get replaced with the string (or string conversion of) the respective parameter.

Regarding your specific question:

```
my_double = 3.14;
my_decimal = 3.14;

Console.WriteLine(“\nMy Double: {0} here your decimal: {1}”, my_double, my_decimal );
//output: My Double: 3.14 here your decimal: 3.14


Console.WriteLine(“\nMy Double: {2} here your decimal: {0}”, "foo", my_decimal, DateTime.Now.ToShortDate() );
//output: My Double: 12/10/2013 here your decimal: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for Concole.WriteLine (or String.Format).  {0} indicates a token that will be replaced by the next parameter in the function....   so...

```
Console.WriteLine("One {0}, Two {1}, Three {2}, One {0}", 1, 2, 3);
```

Would produce:

```
One 1, Two 2, Three 3, One 1
```

You can use {0:n} or other formatting options to render the value in a specific string format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0bfz20d(v=vs.110).aspx